# How to pass args to aspnet_regiis via powershell

Tags: powershell

I have 2 scripts:

```
Launch.ps1
Deploy.ps1
```

Launch simply runs deploy as administrator:

```
clear
$scriptPath      = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$scriptPathToRun = "$scriptPath\Deploy.ps1"
Start-Process -Verb runAs PowerShell -ArgumentList '-noexit','-File', $scriptPathToRun
```

I am trying to pass arguments to aspnet_regiis, I have tried the following:

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow "$env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis" -ArgumentList '–ga',  'domian\serviceAccount'

Start-Process -NoNewWindow "$env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis" -ArgumentList '–ga domian\serviceAccount'

Start-Process -NoNewWindow "$env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis" -ArgumentList @('–ga', 'domian\serviceAccount')

& "$env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis" '–ga domian\serviceAccount'

& "$env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis" '–ga', 'domian\serviceAccount'

& "$env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis" @('–ga', 'domian\serviceAccount')
```

In all these attempts, aspnet_regiis is run but it appears no args are passed to it because the output is just a listing of available aspnet_regiis parameters.

Can someone point out what I'm missing?  Thanks.

Comment: How about just: `& "$env:windir\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis" -ga domian\serviceAccount`

Comment: That worked! If you want credit for the answer, I'm happy to give it if you repost.  I would love to know why Start-Process is not working though, I use the exact same code as line #1 when launching powershell as admin and I pass 3 parameters without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is probably to just run the command using the call/invocation (`&`) operator:

```
& "$env:SystemRoot\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis" -ga domain\serviceAccount
```

If you really wanted to use `Start-Process`, you should be able to write it this way:

```
Start-Process "$env:SystemRoot\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis" "-ga","domain\serviceAccount" -NoNewWindow
```

The first token on that command line is the executable to run (i.e., `-FilePath`). The `-ArgumentList` parameter is an array (i.e., `"-ga","domain\serviceAccount"`).